# React how to show xml view with expand and collapse functions? (react-xml-viewer)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml

Hi I wanted to show xml view in my application. To achieve that I was using react-xml-viewer but also I wanted to add all expand and collapse functions aswell when I check react-xml-viewer I couldn't see it. Is there any way to achieve this with react-xml-viewer or is there any package that I can use. Both solution is ok for me.

```
import React from 'react';
import XMLParser from "react-xml-parser";
import * as s from './XMLDetail.styles';
import XMLViewer from "react-xml-viewer";

const XMLDetail = props => {
const {
    isDarkMode = false,
    appHdrData = "",
    documentData = "",
    isOpenButton=false,
} = props;

//Return
return (
    <div>
        <s.ColumnContainer>
            <s.Customlabel isOpenButton={isOpenButton} >Header</s.Customlabel>
            <s.Customlabel isOpenButton={isOpenButton} >Document</s.Customlabel>
        </s.ColumnContainer>
        <s.XMLDetailContainer>
            <s.XMLContainer isOpenButton={isOpenButton}>
                <XMLViewer xml={appHdrData}/>
            </s.XMLContainer>
            <s.XMLContainer  isOpenButton={isOpenButton}>
                <XMLViewer xml={documentData}/>
            </s.XMLContainer>
        </s.XMLDetailContainer>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default XMLDetail